# Is there any way that white-space: nowrap should show only single dot (.)

Tags: css

I want `white-space: nowrap` to show only single dot when the text is long

For Example the text is `This is a very long text` and I want to display `This is.` not `This is...`

Current Snippet looks like this

```
   <div>
       <div>This is a long text</div>
       <svg></svg>
   </div>
```

Comment: That would be the result of `text-overflow: ellipsis`, not `white-space: nowrap`

Comment: if it's a fixed width you could use a pseudo element with inline block

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62855106/8620333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `display: flex` and `::after` on a containing div:

```css
span {
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 45px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container::after {
  content: '.';
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="container">
    <span>This is a long text</span>
  </div>
  <svg></svg>
</div>
```

Not ideal but it works.

Comment: There is no p tag inside that div :/

Comment: Can you post some code? Same idea should apply depending on the tags

Comment: The `<svg>` complicates it a bit. I'd suggest wrapping the text in a `<span>` if possible. See my edit

Comment: What if the text is too short to overflow?

Comment: @SalmanA Yeah you'd have to know if it would overflow

Comment: Not sure what a workaround could be for that, without using JS

Answer (score 2):

The [`text-overflow` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) allows you to provide a string that is used to signal additional content to users in case of an overflow. I think that would accomplish what you're looking for.

```
text-overflow: "."
```

It's important to say, this function is only available on firefox 9+.

Comment: The support for this is [terrible](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_text-overflow_string)

Comment: @Donut When I apply that in chrome browser it gives me error `invalid property value`

Comment: Yeah, as per @Daniel_Knights's comment this is apparently not really supported outside of Firefox, so it may not be the best solution.