# How to use CSS to display up to three lines in the article. I can’t use the most recommended method at present. I want to ask about other methods?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, webpack

May I ask the effect that I currently want to make the article display up to three lines, and use ellipsis to truncate the excess part
. The syntax I used includes display:-webkit-box;
but when I use webpack to package the code, The display:-webkit-box; will be banned, and the ellipsis ellipsis truncation effect that I want will disappear. If I want to display up to three lines in the article, I would like to show the ellipsis service. Is there any other way to recommend the service?

Thank you.

```css
.demo{
  width: 100px;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  display:-webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient:vertical;  
  -webkit-line-clamp:3;  
  white-space:prep;
  word-break:break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet co
nsectetur adipisicing 

elit. Ali

quid
 culpa, ratione quos harum quae corrupti laudantium maxime voluptas. Numquam nisi consectetur facere perferendi
s in modi ipsum unde eveniet debitis voluptatibus vel dolorem mollitia, nulla odio eum architecto labore aperiam necessitatibus ab! Minima numquam, doloremque laboriosam voluptate debitis dolorem omnis. Soluta.
</div>
```

Comment: So your actual issue is with [tag:webpack]?  Try: https://developpaper.com/question/cant-webpck-compile-this-property-webkit-box-orient-vertical/

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62855106/8620333